# Ruby: get TimeZone component of string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, datetime

I'm working with Date strings in Ruby and want to determine if a string was passed with a timezone or not (beyond simply parsing the text).  If no timezone is supplied, I want to convert it to a certain timezone dependent on other factors.

Example:

```
DateTime.parse("2014-01-01T23:59:00")
=> #<DateTime: 2014-01-01T23:59:00+00:00 ((2456659j,86340s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.parse("2014-01-01T23:59:00Z")
=> #<DateTime: 2014-01-01T23:59:00+00:00 ((2456659j,86340s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
DateTime.parse("2014-01-01T23:59:00PST")
=> #<DateTime: 2014-01-01T23:59:00-08:00 ((2456660j,28740s,0n),-28800s,2299161j)>
```

The problem is that parsing "2014-01-01T23:59:00" and "2014-01-01T23:59:00Z" (with Zulu) yields the same result, when one is specifying "Zulu" and the other isn't.  I'm sure the default behavior is to assume UTC if no zone is supplied.

Comment: Isn't Z the same time zone as UTC? I don't understand the problem

Comment: It is, but I want to determine when a string DOESN'T specify any time zone ('Z' or otherwise)

Comment: Got it, and are you assuming the input is always in ISO 8601 format?

Comment: I'm going to assume that, correct.  I realize I could just use .end_with? but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way.

Answer (score 0):

To check that the date string doesn't end with a time zone, you can check that the minutes and seconds are the end of the string, using this regex: `\d{2}:\d{2}$`

Here are some examples using debuggex to illustrate:

```
\d{2}:\d{2}$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://debuggex.com/r/eO_DpZN6-13WDrJI)